# Redireccionar ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5, webforms

Como posso redireccionar a página que me encontro através de um inputButton html no `ASP NET` `WEB FORMS`

o código do meu `button`:

```
 <input id="ButtonD" style="width: 169px" type="button" value="D"  /><br />
```

Comment: pq tu não utiliza um <a /> ? ou um asp:button, que tem o evento onClick. No evento onClick tu iria executar o código: `Response.Redirect("url");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Você pode atribuir uma função**

Atribuindo ao OnClientClick event para chamar uma função JavaScript em um `asp:Button`:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonD" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick='redirect()' />
```

Ou no `input type="button"`:

```
<input id="ButtonD" style="width: 169px" onclick="redirect()" type="button" value="D"  /><br />
```

JavaScript:

```
function redirect() {
  location.href = 'page.aspx';
}
```

**Você também pode vincular por ID**

jQuery(se for `input type="button"`):

```
$("#ButtonD").click(function(){
   location.href = 'page.aspx';
});
```

jQuery(se for `asp:Button`):

```
$("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").click(function(){
  location.href = 'page.aspx';
});
```

Referência: [link SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034960/asp-net-how-to-make-linkbutton-function-as-hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione:

```
Response.Redirect("sua url destino");
```

No evento Click do botão que você criou.